# Python - Input and Show Results on Web Page

Tags: javascript, python, html, json

I recently started an internship and have been doing relatively well with what they've been giving me; recently however, they gave me a two part task of getting some code to accept an input and return the output while communicating through a web page (I have 0 web experience). I believe I was assigned the extra web portion as a little challenge to start getting me to familiarize myself with interacting with web code.

I was able to write the processing part in Python, where it accepts a string input and returns a json.dump.

This is most likely too vast of a question to expect a specific answer, so if so can anyone point me to a book or some website that may have the steps to solving this issue?

**Steps taken so far**

- Json output in python file (this was part of an API I was using that when called on automatically generated a Json.dump). I'm not allowed to alter this output.
- Did some research on trying to get Python output to a webpage. Imported CGI and got it working.

**Overall Goal**

Pass input in from a webpage input to the Python file where it will process the input and return a json.dump with results. I can try to learn how to lay all of the results out on a web page later. Looking for some quick instructions or even a book I can sit down and read for several hours.

**Side Notes**

I have virtually 0 knowledge of web development. This task seems easy enough, but I just don't know how things mesh together on a web side. From what I know JavaScript is used commonly in conjunction with HTML on development. Is there any way Python can fit into this?

Comment: look for some examples using [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)

Comment: Do you need the user's response to be computed on the server hosting the page? or can you implement whatever algorithm you apply to their data in the web page, and let their computer do the heavy lifting?

Comment: @Aaron I believe what my internship wants is for it to run as a backend system. I don't know exactly what they plan on doing since they were a little vague, but it does seem like it will compute server side.

Comment: Javascript is sent to the client to be executed by their browser (for event driven interfaces, computation, and display graphics more advanced than css or html can handle). html and css generally handle the text, links, images, and forms (simple stuff). A very simple proof of concept would be an html form, and a server built on flask that takes the values entered in the form, and generates a response html page (flask uses a pretty good html template engine).

Comment: [pythonspot](https://pythonspot.com/en/flask-web-app-with-python/) seems to have a pretty decent beginner's tutorial for flask, but definitely do some of your own google-fu.

Comment: @Aaron Thank you! And will the response HTML page be a good thing to print out considering my results are of a json.dump format?

Comment: If you just need to return a json response, flask can do that too https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask